# Passing form modification data as well as data comes though API in the body of Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Whatever the value I'm getting in form using GET method will me updated and send it to through API including form data as well as some extra data like `createdBy`, `lastmodification`, status and so on

```
<form id="form" method="post">
 <div class="image-icon">
  <input class="input" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('imagefile').click();" type="button" value="Choose image"/>
  <img id="myImg" name="user-pic" onclick="changeImage()" src="" style=" position: absolute; right: 0;" width="100%"/>
  <span>
   <img class="edit-icon" src="~/image/edit-pic.png" width="100%"/>
  </span>
  <input class="edit-icon" id="imagefile" name="img" style="visibility: hidden;" type="file">
  </input>
 </div>
 <div class="form">
  <input hidden="" id="userid" type="text"/>
  <label for="fname">
   First Name
  </label>
  <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" value=""/>
  <label for="sname">
   Surname
  </label>
  <input id="sname" name="sname" type="text" value=""/>
  <label for="email">
   Email Address
  </label>
  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value=""/>
  <label for="country">
   Type
  </label>
  <select id="type" name="role">
   <option value="">
   </option>
   <option value="Admin">
    Admin
   </option>
   <option value="Editor">
    Editor
   </option>
   <option value="View">
    View
   </option>
  </select>
  <button id="update" type="submit">
   Update
  </button>
 </div>
</form>
```

```
<script>
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        debugger;
        e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: 'https://localhost:44321/api/users/edit',
        data: {
            id: $('userid').val(),
            imagePath: $('#myImg').src,
            firstName: $('#fname').val(),
            lastName: $('#sname').val(),
            email: $('#email').val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                console.log(Object.keys(data).length);
                console.log(data);
                var len = data.length;
                var txt = "";
  

                txt +=
 
                    "CreatedBy: " + data.createdBy,
                    "Last Modification: " + data.lastmodification,
                    "Status: " + data.status
                   
            }

            console.log("Edit Details" + txt);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }

    });
    });

</script>
```

I have got the data in the form through API and want to update the data. I have send the data through an API including modify form data as well as some more data like created by, modification and status in the body internally.

Comment: I am not able to understand the question here. If you want to send the data again after receiving response from server for user edit api, for that you can call another ajax api using $.ajax inside success function of first $.ajax api call.

Comment: I would like to send form data to update on server as well as some extra data internally like modification date and user id through body. How would i do with AJAx ?

Comment: What do you mean by sending data internally? Do you want to update html attributes?

Comment: I want to pass some random data